# How can I stop the graphicx package from resizing pdfheight/width?

Tags: pdftex, paper-size

I need to provide a pdf file with some specific sizing set by a .cls file which leaves a lot of white space in a page, relevant code shared below.

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}\setlength{\paperheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{13cm}\setlength{\textheight}{17cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.5cm}\addtolength{\headsep}{-\headheight}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}\addtolength{\footskip}{.5\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
```

My problem is that including the graphicx package resizes the pdf size to the paper size variables specified in the .cls file, eliminating all the white space from the output file.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening or to overwrite the graphicx definition of the pdf sizes?

Comment: what is the intention of setting of setting `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` if you do not want them to affect the PDF page size? (LaTeX does not use those settings for anything else)

Comment: I'm not sure why it's done, I've been given this document and told to hand in my paper in the format defined. The only information I could find was a warning saying they use a peculiar page size for their prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a recent graphics distribution, use the `[nosetpagesize]` package option.

Note that if you do this the text block will be as specified by latex but the PDF media dimension will be your installation default, so typically either A4 or US Letter, depending where you are, so the white space in your PDF is unspecified and system dependent.